# Remove Duplicated Items JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, combobox, duplicates, observer-pattern

what is best way to check for duplicate items in JComboBox and remove them? This is not really answered in Java anywhere from what i have researched. Basically when i refresh my JComboBox with the observer pattern it duplicates items, on update. I have tried going down the route of removing all of the items and putting them back in but this causes issues when amending item info(it would take a long time to explain in full).

```
public void setCustomers()
{

 for (Customer curr : Main.getNewCustomerList().getCustomers())
{

    customerCombo.addItem(curr);

}


}


public void setDetails()
{
Customer selected = (Customer) customerCombo.getSelectedItem();
if(selected != null)
{
forenameText.setText(selected.getForename());
surnameText.setText(selected.getSurname());
costperkgText.setText(String.valueOf(selected.getDeliveryCost()));
line1Text.setText(String.valueOf(selected.getColAddress().getAddressLine1()));
line2Text.setText(String.valueOf(selected.getColAddress().getAddressLine2()));
cityText.setText(String.valueOf(selected.getColAddress().getCity()));
postcodeText.setText(String.valueOf(selected.getColAddress().getPostcode()));

}
else 
{
    ClearText();
}
}

public void ammendDetails()
{
Customer selected = (Customer) customerCombo.getSelectedItem();
if(selected != null)
{
selected.setForename(forenameText.getText());
selected.setSurname(surnameText.getText());
System.out.print(costperkgText.getText());
selected.setDeliveryCost(Double.valueOf(costperkgText.getText()));
Address newAddress = new Address(line1Text.getText(), line2Text.getText(), cityText.getText(), postcodeText.getText());
selected.setColAddress(newAddress);


}
else
{
  ClearText();        
}

}

 public void ClearText()
{
forenameText.setText("");
surnameText.setText("");
costperkgText.setText("");
line1Text.setText("");
line2Text.setText("");
cityText.setText("");
postcodeText.setText("");
}


@Override
public void update()
{
setCustomers();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
  public void setCustomers(){

        customerCombo.removeAllItems();

        for (Customer curr : Main.getNewCustomerList().getCustomers()){

                 customerCombo.addItem(curr);

        }


    }
```

Comment: This has already been ruled out in my question as it causes the amending of details to set the details of the current selected Customer to the first customer in the combo's.

Comment: 1+, seems like a good solution to me. `it causes the amending of details to set the details of the current selected Customer to the first customer in the combo's` - no idea what that means. But if you are saying that you do some processing when an item is selected, then the solution is to remove the ActionListener, update the combo box and then add the ActionListener back to the combo box

Comment: @bSky Save the currently selected customer in a field before resetting the view with setCustomers, then set the previously selected customer again